# GWT UiBinder - Execute JS after template is rendered?

Tags: javascript, java, templates, gwt

I have a div in my UiBinder template with the ID "test" and want to execute some jQuery stuff on it. If I execute the native method at the end of my UiBinder java class, the javascript call fails, since the div seems not to be there yet:

```
public MyWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    AppUtils.initializeSomething();
}
```

A work around is to use a timer and delay my JS code a bit. This works, but is pretty ugly in my opinion. Is there any clean solution to execute my javascript, if the UiBinder template is fully loaded?

```
public MyWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    new Timer(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AppUtils.initializeSomething();
        };
    }.schedule(1000);

}
```

The native method:

```
public static native void initializeSomething()/*-{

     $wnd.$('#test').doSomeJsStuff();
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public MyWidget() {
>     initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
>     AppUtils.initializeSomething();
> }
> ```

As this is just the constructor, at this point the DOM elements all exist, but have not yet been attached, so any code that tries to find attached dom elements will fail (for example, jQuery will try to do `document.getElementById` to work out `$('#test')`, which will fail since the widget is not yet attached to the document).

Instead, you have two basic options:

- Run the initialization right away, but actually pass in the dom element instead of trying to find it (and failing), or
- Wait until the dom element is actually attached before attempting to initialize.

---

Running the initialization is just a matter of already knowing which element you will modify. Since you are using uiBinder, you can make a `Element` field in your Java class and ask it to be assigned to some element which has a `ui:field` attribute set on it of the same name. This is like how you are currently setting the ID of the element to "test", and then expecting to find it with `$('#test'). Something like this:

In your .ui.xml file:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <div ui:field="testElement">...</div>
  ...
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In your .java class:

```
@UiField Element testElement;
```

Then in your JSNI method you can pass in the element or refer to it when you call it. Here's what your `initializeSomething` and constructor could look like:

```
public MyWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    AppUtils.initializeSomething(this.testElement);
}
public static native void initializeSomething(Element elt)/*-{
    //jQuery lets you wrap a dom element instead of finding it,
    //and we already know where it is
    $wnd.$(elt).doSomeJsStuff();
}-*/;
```

---

Next, wait until attached to the DOM to run `doSomeJsStuff()` - two simple ways for this. In raw JS, you'd do this the first way, though I suggest that this is very wrong for JS. So here's the first, wrong way:

```
//make the elements
MyWidget widget = new MyWidget();
//attach them to the dom (note that if you attach to a different
//                        parent, that parent too must be attached
//                        and so on).
RootPanel.get().add(widget);
//now that we are attached, run the setup code!
widget.doSomeJsStuff();
```

This is clearly silly - we're writing a class, and that class should be smart enough to take care of itself!

Lets try again, this time instructing the class to run `doSomeJsStuff()` once it has attached. There are two methods that could do this work, both `onAttach` and `onLoad` - without specific details about what `doSomeJsStuff` does, I don't know what you need, but `onLoad` is the easier one to work with.

It is important to note that these methods are called each time the widget is attached, not just the first time. If this is important to you, you might need to check that the widget has not already been attached. If not, all we need is this:

```
@Override
protected void onLoad() {
  doSomeJsStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that great answer! Very detailed and both versions work perfectly for me!